# Probability that no two of the 3 balls drawn are blue

Tags: probability, combinations

> A box contains $b$ red balls , $2b$ white balls , $3b$ blue balls where $b$ is a positive integer. 3 balls are selected randomly without replacement and $A$ is the event that "No two of the 3 drawn balls are blue". Prove that $P(B)=1/2$ for all values of $b$.

Here i have tried adding the probabilities of all the cases where only a single or no blue ball is chosen in any of the three chances . I also tried it reverse by subtracting the sum of probablities of choosing 2 or all 3 from the blue ball from 1 but still not getting the answer .can anyone help me with that.

Comment: What is $B$?  $\quad $

Comment: Actually the answer is evident already from the symmetry between blue and non-blue balls.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of balls that are blue among the balls that are drawn.
Assuming $A$ and $B$ are the same event, then drawing without replacement, we have the following probabilities:

\begin{align}
P(X=0) = \frac{\dbinom{3b}{0}\dbinom{3b}{3}}{\dbinom{6b}{3}}, \\
P(X=1) = \frac{\dbinom{3b}{1}\dbinom{3b}{2}}{\dbinom{6b}{3}}, \\
P(B) = P(X=0) + P(X=1).
\end{align}

Similarly, when we compute the probability of drawing $2$ or $3$ blue balls,
$P(X = 3) = P(X = 0)$ and $P(X = 2) = P(X = 1)$.
But
$$ P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + P(X = 2) + P(X = 3) = 1, $$
since $X$ can only be an integer from $0$ to $3$ inclusive.
Therefore

\begin{align}
2P(X = 0) + 2P(X = 1) &= 1, \\
P(B) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) &= \frac12. \\
\end{align}

Due to the fact that there are also exactly $3b$ balls that are **not** blue,
this same argument could be made without showing specific formulas for the individual probabilities. The probability of drawing $3$ blue balls is exactly the same as the probability of drawing $3$ balls that are not blue, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

*Cogito*

The number of ways 3 non-blue balls may be drawn = $(3b)(3b - 1)(3b -2)$.

The number of ways 3 balls may be drawn = $(6b)(6b - 1)(6b -2)$

Answer (score 0):

No two of the 3 drawn balls are blue $\equiv$ Exact one ball is blue + None of three balls is blue.

Now, Probability of Exact one ball is blue

$=\frac{^{(b+2b)}C_2\cdot^{3b}C_1}{^{(b+2b+3b)}C_3}=\frac{\frac{(3b)!\cdot(3b)!}{(3b-2)!\cdot2!\cdot(3b-1)!\cdot 1!}}{\frac{(6b)!}{3!\cdot(6b-3)!}}=\frac{\frac{9b^2(3b-1)}{2}}{b\cdot(6b-1)(6b-2)}=\frac{9b}{4(6b-1)}\quad(\because b\ne\frac{1}{3})$

Probability of none of three balls is
blue

$=\frac{^{b+2b}C_3}{^{(b+2b+3b)}C_3}=\frac{\frac{(3b)!}{(3b-3)!\cdot3!}}{\frac{(6b)!}{3!\cdot(6b-3)!}}=\frac{\frac{b(3b-1)(3b-2)}{2}}{{b(6b-1)(6b-2)}}=\frac{3b-2}{4(6b-1)}\quad(\because b\ne\frac{1}{3})$

Therefore, probability of no two of the 3 drawn balls are blue

$=\frac{9b}{4(6b-1)}+\frac{3b-2}{4(6b-1)}=\frac{12b-2}{4(6b-1)}=\frac{2}{4}=\boxed{\frac{1}2}\ \quad \square$